# How to compare 2 variables to know if the second is including in the first?

Tags: shell

I have 2 variables T1 and T2 and I need to test if the variable T1 is included in the variable T2
I have written the following code for a shell scrip (sh) but it display NO instead of OK

```
T2="/volume1/video/Films/Flicka The Little Girl (2006).avi"

T1="Flicka The Little Girl"

if [[ "$T2" == *"$T1"* ]]
then
  echo "OK";
else
  echo "NO";
fi
```

If anybody could explain me how to do for correct coding....it will be very very kind :)

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have `!#/bin/bash` at the top of your script? How are you executing it? What is the output of `echo $SHELL` on your terminal?

Comment: No I do not have  put !#/bin/bash in the first line. I just test to add it but I have an error message (not found) 

I have save the script with the following name  "titi.sh" and I launch it as : sh titi.sh

echo $SHELL ==> /bin/sh

Comment: The comparison you are running works only in bash. If you install bash on your system, you can get the script working.

Comment: Ok ok and is it a solution without to install bash ? I thought that with the command find or sed or grep I can do it but I'm not enough competent unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of bash, you can use a simple grep command to arrive at the solution:

```
$ cat x.sh 
#!/bin/sh
T2="/volume1/video/Films/Flicka The Little Girl (2006).avi"

T1="Flicka The Little Girl"

if echo "$T2" | grep -q "$T1"; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "NO"
fi

$ ./x.sh 
OK
```

Comment: Right now this only works if T1 is a valid BRE that matches itself. To work in other cases, perhaps you want `grep -F`?